# Using auto-filter for matching data across sheets using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 sheets :

Input sheet which consist of the following data :

[image: Input Sheet]

Sheet1 consist of the following data :

[image: Sheet1]

And the output should look like :

[image: Sample output]

My idea is that the macro should pick up HR Position from **Input** sheet one by one, filter it in **Sheet1** and find the number of corresponding Task/roles, then paste it in **output** sheet with the corresponding user and company codes.

My code so far :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    LastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
cntr = 2
For i = 2 To LastRow
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Cells(cntr, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("A" & i).Value

    Set Range1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("C" & i)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range1
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A2:B").Copy _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("C2")

    End With
    cntr = cntr + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

I am stuck because i am not able to find how to repeat corresponding user and company codes in Output tab

Comment: are you sure you want to use vba? it can just be done easily using `vlookup` or combination of `index` and `match`, which are available functions in excel.

Comment: @Atreyagaurav You are correct. but I have multiple matches of HR position in Sheet1 which i want in Output sheet. so the format itself is changing in output sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than filtering, you could use some of the collection objects that are available to help you out, like `scripting.dictionary`

I have created a dummy version of your data, like the below image

[image]

an used this code to produce the output in column J accross

```
Sub testing()

Dim rngFirstTable As Excel.Range
Dim rngSecondTable As Excel.Range
Dim dicFilter As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim dicTasks As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim rngInspect As Excel.Range
Dim lngRowSource As Long
Dim lngRowDest As Long
Dim rngDisplayTopLeft As Range
Dim rngDisplay As Range

lngRowDest = 1

Set rngFirstTable = Range("A1:A4")
Set rngSecondTable = Range("F1:G5")
Set rngDisplayTopLeft = Range("J1")
Set rngDisplay = rngDisplayTopLeft

'   Set dictionary up containing Key's of the HR Roles
For Each rngInspect In rngSecondTable.Columns(1).Cells
    If dicFilter.Exists(rngInspect.value) Then
        dicFilter(rngInspect.value).Add _
            CStr(dicTasks.Count + 1), _
            rngInspect.Offset(0, 1).value
    Else
        Set dicTasks = New Scripting.Dictionary
        dicTasks.Add "1", rngInspect.Offset(0, 1).value
        dicFilter.Add rngInspect.value, dicTasks
    End If
Next rngInspect

For lngRowSource = 2 To rngFirstTable.Rows.Count

    '   Copy the "header info" columns
    rngDisplay.Resize(1, 3).value = rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 1).Resize(1, 3).value

    '   Extract the relevant dictionary corresponding to HR Role HR Position
    Set dicTasks = dicFilter(rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 3).value)

    '   Use the array from .items() to transpose to array equiv to range
    rngDisplay.Offset(0, 4).Resize(dicTasks.Count, 1).value = _
        Application.Transpose(dicTasks.Items())

    '   Increment the offset from the top left cell
    lngRowDest = lngRowDest + dicTasks.Count
    Set rngDisplay = rngDisplayTopLeft.Offset(lngRowDest - 1, 0)

    Set dicTasks = Nothing

Next lngRowSource

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Nathan
Though i am getting an error at

Set dicTasks = dicFilter(rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 3).Value) as "object required " 
Any idea why?

Comment: can you give some more details, are you using my data for example?

Comment: Okk nevermind.. I have made it dynamic using lastrow function and its working now. Thanks a bunch, nathan. God bless you

Comment: @Nathan_Sav : I am using his code but i am facing error at line Set dicTasks = dicFilter(rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 3).Value) as "object required " 
If in input sheet, data is "Hello Dear" and in sheet 2, data is "hello dear", then it is throwing an error because it is not able to catch that value